# is it possible to mount hostname specific nfs share in /etc/fstab

Tags: linux, nfs, fstab

I want to mount a hostname specific nfs Filesystem in /etc/fstab.

`10.0.0.1:/testmy/<hostname> /nfs_for_host`

if there any Variable to do this ?

Comment: http://chrisschuld.com/2008/11/auto-mounting-nfs-shares-in-etcfstab/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the following to your /etc/fstab :

```
10.0.0.1:/testmy/<hostname>  /nfs_for_host nfs _netdev,defaults,user,auto,noatime,intr   0 0
```

Explanation of the options (from man 8 mount and man 5 nfs):

- **_netdev**: The filesystem resides on a device that requires network access.
- **defaults**: Use default options: rw, suid, dev, exec, auto, nouser, async, and relatime.
- **user**: Allow an ordinary user to mount the filesystem .
- **auto**: Can be mounted with the -a option.
- **noatime**: Access timestamps are not updated when a file is read.
- **intr**: Allow signals to interrupt file operations on this mount point.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it in fstab, but you can use NIS and automount to accomplish the same thing.

See this:
http://www.timgalyean.com/2010/03/automounting-home-directories-with-nis-and-nfs/